# ajaxifying simplenews subscribe

Tags: ajax, emails

is there a way to ajaxify simplenews subscribe to newsletter block?
I was thinking of hook_form_alter ing it and adding my ajax callback, But its not working.

`my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'simplenews_block_form_7182') {
    $ajax = array(
          'callback' => 'simplenews_block_form_validate',
          'wrapper' => 'simplenews_wrapper_block',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade',
          'progress' => array('message' => '')
        );
    $form['submit']['#executes_submit_callback'] = TRUE;
    $form['submit']['#ajax'] = $ajax;`

but now when I trigger the submit button i get 
`Fatal error:  Call to undefined function simplenews_block_form_validate() in /includes/form.inc on line 1460`

Comment: Callback needs to be a valid function. Not just any function, but one that's written to handle your AJAX data. Name your callback in a way that prevents mistaking it with native simplenews functions and post it's code here.

Comment: I wanted to call simplenews callback as I dont want to alter anything to the form. I just dont want that page refresh after submitting. Is it possible?

Comment: Simplenews does not provide submitting AJAX callback (or I don't know about one). You need to write your own if you want it. Possible, for sure. But you can't just take validation or submit handler and tell it to be an AJAX callback.

Comment: although it would be cool if one can just simply do that, Dont you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, you can achieve this using [**form_load_include**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) OR [**require_once**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Try **form_load_include()** OR **require_once()** in your form alter.

`function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 switch ($form_id) {
    case 'simplenews_block_form_ID'://add your form_id
        require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . "/modules/contrib/simplenews/includes/simplenews.subscription"); 
        //OR
        form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'simplenews', 'includes/simplenews.subscription');
    break;
   } 
}`

[Reference](https://drupal.org/node/921398#comment-3987258)

Comment: Works well and what.. Its the Drupal standard.

Comment: Great!! enjoy..